# select tag is not working in dynamic table for multiple row

Tags: javascript, html

in my code dynamically add the table row with some input types number, textfield, and selectfield
and print the output in a total.. so my problem is that the output is print for only first row it didnot gives the output for others row... when i remove the selectfield it works fine for remaining field.. so what changes I have to make do that my code is works for selectfield also ?

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;            
        }
       var listitems= row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
              listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
            }
    } else {
        alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");

    }
}



function calculate(elementID) {
    var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=qty]')[0].value;
    var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=price]')[0].value;
    var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name^=sel]')[0].value;

    var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=total]')[0];
    var myResult1 = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3;
    total.value = myResult1;

}    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr id='row_0'>
            <p>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" required="required" name="qty" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                     <label for="sel">Price</label>                 
                    <select name="sel" id="sel" oninput="calculate('row_0')" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Total</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="total">
                </td>
            </p>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What did you wrong?**

- You forgot to select as well as you have `input` also the `select`.

**What have I changed?**

- The trick is here change `row.querySelectorAll("input, select");`
  instead of `row.getElementsByTagName("input")`

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;            
        }
       var listitems= row.querySelectorAll("input, select");
       
            for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
              listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
            }
          
    } else {
        alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");

    }
}



function calculate(elementID) {
    var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=qty]')[0].value;
    var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=price]')[0].value;
    var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name^=sel]')[0].value;
    var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=total]')[0];
    var myResult1 = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3;
    total.value = myResult1;

}    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr id='row_0'>
            <p>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" required="required" name="qty" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                     <label for="sel">Price</label>                 
                    <select name="sel" id="sel" oninput="calculate('row_0')" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Total</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="total">
                </td>
            </p>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Here

```
function calculate(tableID) { // elementID to tableID
   var mainRow = document.getElementById(tableID); // elementID to tableID
}
```

Set Select box

```
setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
                row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
                }
                var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
                for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
                    listitems[i].setAttribute("onchange", "calculate('" + row.id + "')");


                }
                var selectbox = row.getElementsByTagName("select")
                selectbox[0].setAttribute("onchange", "calculate('" + row.id + "')");
            } else {
                alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");

            }
        }



        function calculate(tableID) {
            debugger;
            var mainRow = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=qty]')[0].value;
            var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=price]')[0].value;
            var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=sel]')[0].value;

            var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=total]')[0];
            var myResult1 = myBox1 * myBox2 * myBox3;
            total.value = myResult1;

        } </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
   <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr id='row_0'>
            <p>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" required="required" name="qty" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                     <label for="sel">Price</label>                 
                    <select name="sel" id="sel" oninput="calculate('row_0')" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Total</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="total">
                </td>
            </p>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```